# Highlight filtered rows in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a array that needs to highlight duplicate values. This is what I have so far..

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | unique: 'names'" >
   <td>  {{ x }} </td>
</tr>

<style>
.duplicate{
background: yellow;

}
</style>
```

**Controller:**

```
 angular.module('myApp', []).controller('nameCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.names = [
                'Bob',
                'Dan',
                'Philip',
                'Philip',

            ];
        });
```

**EDIT:** In the example above `"Philip"` would be highlighted and would have `duplicate` class

Comment: what problem you are facing here ?

Comment: Please have a look at the update above.

Comment: first of all use that `class=""` in your tag or use `ng-class=""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="name in names | unique">
        <td ng-class="{ 'duplicate': names.indexOf(name) !== names.lastIndexOf(name) }">{{name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

This applies the `duplicate` class for elements where the `indexOf` returns a different value than the `lastIndexOf`. This can only happen for items that are in the array more than once.

JSFiddle available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ruknkwq0/1/).

If you don't want to filter out the duplicates, you can use this:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="name in names track by $index">
        <td ng-class="{ 'duplicate': names.indexOf(name) !== names.lastIndexOf(name) }">{{name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, count) in names | count" >
  <td ng-class="{your-highlight-class: count > 1 }">  {{ key }} </td>
</tr>

app.filter('count', function ( ) {
  return function (collection) {

    var result = {};
    collection.forEach( function( elm ) {

      if(!result[elm]) {
        result[elm] = 0;
      }

      result[elm]++;
    });

    return result;
  }
}]);
```